# Javascript console: click links with certain title/text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to click all the links on a page, where the identifiers for the link I want to click are only a unique href, a generic title, and the text of the link.

I want to click all the links whose title text (or even the text of the link) are the same.

I've tried adapting other scripts for the purpose, but have had no luck.  My current iteration is this:

```
var links = document.getElementByTitle("Download");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
links[i].click();
}
```

which doesn't work because there is no method getElementByTitle.  I feel like this is the best way to convey what I'm trying to do, though.

Comment: _"I want to click all the links whose title text (or even the text of the link) are the same."_ - The same as what? Are you saying you want to find any links that have the same title as other links and click all of those? Or where the title is the same as some predefined string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"there is no method getElementByTitle."*

No, but you can use the [`querySelectorAll()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[title="Download"]');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].click();
}
```

That is supported in all modern browsers, including IE >= 9, or even IE8 with CSS2 selectors. Otherwise you can do this:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].title === "Download")
        links[i].click();
}
```

Comment: That code works wonderfully, except this brings up a new issue.  Is there any way I can open each link in a new tab, or wait a specified time between each click?  Like a thread.sleep() command? or a control+click() instead of regular click()?

Comment: There is no `sleep()`, but you can restructure the loop to work with `setTimeout()` instead. Except that clicking the first link would navigate away from the current page so it would never get to the second link (unless they are links to elements in the same page). I don't think you can trigger control+click, but you could try `window.open()` with the href from each anchor.

Comment: I'm still running into issues where only the last link is showing as being clicked.  It's possible that the script is blowing through all the links, but each previous link's loading period is being canceled by the current link loading (thus making only the last link 'clicked').  I haven't had any luck with the setTimeout.  Even when I set the parameter to 7000, only the last download load.  I apologize for my incompetence in JavaScript, this is my first try at coding something

Comment: You can't load multiple links into the same (current) window or tab - that doesn't make sense, because the first one will replace the current page. `setTimeout()` won't help with that. I don't believe JS can control opening in a new tab, but you can use `window.open(links[i].href,"_blank")` instead of `.click()` to open each link in a new window - some browsers will default to opening in new tabs when you do this. (But then some popup blockers won't let you open lots of windows at once...)